# Is HTC Sensation 4G based on Android 2.2 or Android 2.3 OS?

Tags: htc-sensation

Is [HTC Sensation 4G](http://www.cellhub.com/t-mobile-cell-phones/htc-sensation-4g-carbon-grey.html) based on Android 2.2 or Android 2.3 OS?

Answer (score 3):

HTC Sensation comes with the Android 2.3 Gingerbread but "wearing" the HTC Sense (3.0) mod.

Sensation is also in-line for an upgrade to ICS (Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4.0)) early in 2012.